# check which dictionary keys corresponding arrays contain a certain string

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary like this dict = [String:[String]]
I want to be able to check if a given string is contained in any of the arrays in the dictionary. If so I would like to then gather the keys for those arrays and create a new array of those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here searching for the word "so":

```
let dict = ["hi":["so", "im"], "fi": ["to", "le"]]
let keys = Array(dict.filter{ $1.contains("so") }.keys)
print(keys)
```

For your second request where a match is enough:

```
let values = ["hi":["so", "im"], "fish": ["to", "ler"]]
let keys = Array(values.filter{ $1.contains{ string in string.contains("s") } }.keys)
print(keys)
```

Comment: This is great, how can i do that even if part of the string matches it will include the key as well for example it checked for just "s". "hi" would still be a key that is printed